# Cloudtrail explicit deny in AWS Org fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-organizations

There are only 5 users in IAM other than the root account. This policy has an explicit deny and is attached at the root level (attached photo), but it doesn't work.

"Doesn't work" means - in the AWS console, I click on Stop Logging and it stops the logging. Also, I ran the command to stop logging in the CLI and that also stopped the logging - so this explicit deny is failing somewhere.

Please note that this test is done on an IAM member account and not the root account.  I only used the root account to set up the SCP.  The IAM member account is a super user and does almost all of the "admin work" on AWS.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "DenycloudtrailStopLogging",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "cloudtrail:StopLogging"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

[image: AWS SCP]

[image: inherited permissions]

Do the IAM users need to be linked somewhere else too?  They aren't in the OUs but they are still accounts in IAM so I would figure that they all inherit the root permissions (photo above)

Also thought an **explicit deny trumps every other decision** in all other policies, so what reasons could there be that this policy doesn't work?  These are the only 2 Service Control Policies (Full Access and Deny Cloudtrail stop logging).

Are there any other factors aside from creating the policy and attaching it to the root - because I thought this is all we had to do?  Some kind of service or role exemption that could be placed elsewhere?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Have you tried invoking the API directly (or via the CLI) and not gotten an Access Denied? Or are you inferring the use of the API from some other operation?

Comment: More to the point, I would include `DeleteTrail` in the deny list.

Comment: I clicked on Stop Logging in the AWS console but it still stopped logging.  Also I ran the command to stop logging in the CLI and it also stopped logging.  Will update the post, thanks.  Sorry "doesn't work" means, are there any other factors aside from assigning the policy to the root and using it, because I thought this is all we had to do.  And thanks, I will use DeleteTrail after I get stopLogging working - appreciate that

Comment: Attaching to the root OU should be sufficient. The only thing that I can suggest is looking at the account itself in the Organizations console, and verifying that it's inherited the SCP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the code above into a new "permission boundary policy" in IAM did the trick, instead of an SCP.

Permission boundary policies in IAM limit IAM users, whereas SCPs in AWS Organizations limit AWS Organization accounts specifically.

Answer (score 2):

Service Control Policies (SCPs) don’t apply to the payer (a.k.a. master) account. They only apply to member accounts of the Organization. That means if you want to deny specific actions in the payer account, you will have to do it in a different way.

The reasoning is that with SCPs you can also restrict the root user of the targeted account. If it would apply to the payer account, you could effectively lock yourself out of the whole Organization and all of its accounts.

One thing to note: There should not be much activity, as little users as possible, and no actual workloads running in the payer account. Its sole purpose should be to manage the Organization (member accounts, billing, SCPs, and CloudFormation StackSets) and this should be as automated as possible. Manually accessing the payer account beyond the absolutely necessary, or running additional workloads to run, opens a great security risk, because if the payer account gets compromised it can get your whole organization in trouble.

For a secure setup, please have a look at [AWS Control Tower](https://aws.amazon.com/controltower/) or if that isn’t available in your region yet, the [AWS Landing Zone Solution](https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/implementations/aws-landing-zone/).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I am running the cloudtrail tests on an IAM account that is not the root account.  Sorry, I will add this to the post.  I agree with what you are saying, and only used the root account to create an IAM member account that is the superuser who does mostly everything.  I went back to this root account to set up the SCP to prevent my personal member account from being able to stop the logging in Cloudtrail

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a misunderstanding. Please note that I am not talking of the root user and IAM users. I am talking of the AWS Payer Account (the master account of your AWS Organization) and its member accounts (other AWS accounts that you have created in or invited to your Organization). Granted, this can be a bit confusing, that's why we call it IAM user (or root user) in the context of IAM and AWS accounts in the context of Organizations.

Comment: Hi - I pay for the AWS accounts with my credit card and should own the only master root account.  I should be in charge of all top-level accounts.  That said, I used the master account to create my IAM user account, which I then setup all the other IAM user accounts with. Hope I understood all your points correctly?

Comment: I am not talking about IAM Users here. SCPs are a concept of the AWS Organization service. They apply to AWS accounts, not IAM Users. If you set an SCP, it will not restrict any IAM Users in the Organization’s Payer Account. It will only restrict IAM Users (and Roles) in the Organization’s member accounts. Please understand that when referring to “accounts” I am not speaking of users.

Comment: Looked into this again and think I am understanding it as SCPs will only work on members invited to the AWS organization, as you are trying to explain. SCPs have nothing to do with IAM users in AWS, so the way I wanted to set it up originally would never work because again, SCPs are only at the org level and org level users.  The AWS accounts that I use to create instances in EC2 with, or upload files to S3 with - these SCPs can't be applied to those types of accounts.

Comment: You‘re almost there. SCPs can be applied to all AWS accounts in an AWS Organization, except the payer account (which is the top level account, managing the SCPs). Again, this has nothing to do with IAM Users. Please distinguish between AWS accounts (where you deploy resources) and IAM Users (that are used to access an AWS account).

Comment: Ok, I think this is where my problem is.  I have the root account at the AWS Org, and a separate IAM user (also mine) that I use to access the AWS account but this one is not part of the Organization.  I want the SCP to work on the IAM user account so maybe I need to invite that IAM user account to the Organization for the SCP to work?  Right now, the IAM user account isn't a member of any Org and I originally thought the SCP at the root level would reach that IAM user account - but this IAM user account can still stop CloudTrail logging even with the attached policy code that I wrote above.

Comment: Please understand: There is no such thing as an "IAM User Account". There are "IAM Users" and "AWS Accounts". They are completely separate concepts and have nothing to do with eachother. An IAM User is never part of an Org. It is an IAM Entity. It is different from an "AWS Account", which has nothing to do with IAM. You use an IAM User (or the root user) to log into an AWS Account. An AWS Account can be member of an AWS Organization. Each Organization has at least the Payer Account, and zero or more Member Accounts. Each AWS account has one root user and zero or more IAM Users.

Comment: OK thank you - but in order for the SCP to work on the AWS accounts, does it need to be invited to the Org?  Because the AWS account I use now is not affected by the root level SCP, but it is also not in the Org.  Or the last answer which is, it will not work at all.  I think because they have nothing to do with each other - it will not work at all. I just want to believe they will... :(

Comment: Yes. An SCP can only affect resources in Member Accounts of the AWS Organization. They never affect resources in AWS Accounts that are not part of the AWS Organization. They also don'rt affect resources in the Payer (a.k.a. Master) Account of the Organization. AWS Accounts can become Member Accounts by 1/ being invited into the Organization, and 2/ being created from within the AWS Organization's Payer Account.